# install more then one apps in one apk or make two project one?

Tags: android, package

i making an application ,there is an other app that i want to add to my project, it is a source code and i allow to edit and add to the  app menu of my app , but i get too many errors and its not fixable. 
**remember**: i don't want to create an other `manifest.XML` or add another icon to menu if i could fix the errors i would added them to app menu because its working in its own project, i want a new app install with my app.
1. is there a way that the installer install more then one app? it would hep a lot

if not perhaps you can help me fix it this way:

error:
i add the package(java files) of the app and i have access to its file, all the XML are added and if there is an error i tried to fix them, i didn't run the project because i was shore i get errors , i fixed all that i could but now i get an error like this:
now i think i have to import its `R class` but then , all of values are in the XML and there is no need to bring the R class:

its own R class with suggestion of android studio:
`import com.softwaredownload.app.R` and R is red when i run it:

`Error:(75, 25) error: package R does not exist.`

ops! why do i get error for my own package Java files ?! i also clean and rebuild and restart the android studio. i mean when i added them at the first place and i fixed the errors at the top of them was the green mark that there is no error.
also , all of the project files are added the proper way but they are not working like the source code, i mean all the XML files are edited and fixed.

Comment: Are you trying to include the source code of a library, or a whole second app? If an app, you cannot merge them unless done manually.

Comment: Source code, they are not the same but I want them both, two sources code for two different app.

Comment: Im asking if you have two applications or one library and one application. There are differences

Comment: two application

Answer (score 1):

1. No, you can't install another app in tandem with your own app
2. Remove all `the.old.package.R`-import statements from the top of your pasted classes
3. Rebuild/run the project
4. Android Studio will then suggest importing your own package's `R.class`. Accept this recommendation. This requires that you've copied *all* resources (not just the layouts) from the old app into your new app.

Comment: i tried this : `import com.softwaredownload.app.R` it fix the error but then R become red again. and it will not fix it.

Comment: As I said, remove all references to the old package name from your import statements in every class, then rebuild the project, then import your app's R class. The resources file is only regenerated if the project doesn't contain any errors.

Answer (score 0):

i fixed the error like this:

1. it is impossible for two app to add to one installer APK but i just edit them both and i added them to the project than i edited `manifest.XML` and add two icon to android menu.

2.there is no need to bring the `R class` , it was an android studio error that fixed.